# Does polymorph change your ability to think?

Tags: dnd-5e, polymorph, ability-scores

Polymorph says that they cannot cast spells in the new form, their intelligence hits the floor, but they maintain personality.

Does this mean they also lose the ability of Logical thinking? As an example,  does turning into a frog give you the intellectual capability of one? 
As a result, can you be trapped in a frog who does not know it is not a frog?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Strictly speaking, **you are correct**. Despite retaining your personality, you are constrained by the physical and mental capabilities of your new form.

If you were friendly to the party before, you still are friendly to them as a frog, but communication might be an issue. ;)

I don't mean to say that I agree with the complete lack of logical thinking, or of the frog not knowing it's not a frog (because it retains memories). I just mean that the spell, RAW, forces the player to roleplay the character as a member of the new form, as much as sensibly possible. ^_^

Comment: I'd like to point out that the problems of a *polymorphed* creature came up in the novel "EXILE" which is the second part of the Dark Elf trilogy by R. A. Salvatore (1990).
Clacker, a pech, found his personality deteriorating the longer it was trapped in it's new form, a Hook Horror. Over time it was ever harder to not give in to the "monster side" and becoming a threat to it's friends. This is in line with the spell's description from AD&D 2nd Edition and I find this "urgency to change back" a nice twist.